# How to merge stepped topography layers to single solid mesh

Tags: mesh, faces

I created a stepped topography model using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNR0fvlUsaE).

[image]

The different layers of my model consist of closed slices of the same height. The slices of the planes partially touch each other at the upper or lower surface.

[image]

How can I combine the mesh of the model so that it is only a closed mesh, without inner faces? So I want to have a single, completely closed volume.

[image]